# Atlassian Confluence $soyTemplateRendererHelper.getRenderedTemplateHtml

Tags: jira, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have an Atlassian Confluence, at the top of the page where the navigation bar should be I have the following string of text, which appears to be an error:

```
$soyTemplateRendererHelper.getRenderedTemplateHtml("com.atlassian.auiplugin:aui-experimental-soy-templates", "aui.page.header.soy", $templateParameters)
```

After some investigation I have noticed that the plugin is not activated:

Confluence Soy Template Renderer for Velocity(soyTemplateRendererHelperContext)

I assume this is the problem, however due to it being a core module, I cannot do anything within the Confluence Admin GUI, could anypoint point me in the right direction of how I can activate this plugin?

I have searched high and low for documentation on this but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

We got this message when our disk was full. If the other method isn't working check if you have space left.

Comment: CHECK THIS FIRST!  Don't execute the SQL statement until you check this!

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: The other answer by Jacob Clark suggesting a Bandana table update is dangerous as written and it should not be used.

To fix:

- Navigate to Toolgear->Add-ons.
- View the page source and fish the security token out of the HTML `<head>`. It should look like this:
  `meta id="atlassian-token" content="b50c842e84b3963f828b7da729ecb1cd80e91505" name="atlassian-token"`
- Copy and paste the "content" part of the token into the atl_token query parameter into the URL below, then access the URL from your browser:
  `http://YOURJIRASYSTEM/admin/enableplugin.action?moduleKey=com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.soy:soyTemplateRendererHelperContext&atl_token=b50c842e84b3963f828b7da729ecb1cd80e91505`

Once you click on this, you'll be dumped into an old plugin administration page that is not correctly formatted...but the module will be enabled.

To verify that all is fixed, go back to `Toolgear->Add-ons`, select `System` from the dropdown, click on the `Confluence Soy Template Support` to expand it, and click on the `+` icon to verify that all of the modules are enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by executing the following PostgreSQL query on the confluencedb database to enable the Confluence Soy Template Renderer.

```
update BANDANA set BANDANAVALUE='<map><entry><string>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.doctheme:velocityHelper</strong><boolean>true</boolean></entry><entry><string>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.soy::soyTemplateRendererHelperContext</string><boolean>true</boolean></entry></map>'
```

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks.

[the solution in atlassian did not work](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Comment+Box+Disappears%3A+$soyTemplateRendererHelper.getRenderedTemplateHtml)

Comment: This is probably caused by the underlying issue [CONF-22390](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-22390), in which Confluence sometimes randomly disable Velocity helper modules on its own accord.

Comment: **WARNING! The update statement above is dangerous and it will trash significant parts of your Confluence instance!** As Adrian Ellis notes below, it will overwrite all of the data in the Bandana table, which you really do not want to do.